# Running unit tests from MSBuild script

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, mstest

I am running unit tests (MSTest) from my MSBuild script:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">   
  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ContinuousDeploymentProof.Web.Tests\bin\$(Configuration)\ContinuousDeploymentProof.Web.Tests.dll"/>  
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MsTestCommand>"$(MsTestExePath)" @(TestAssemblies->'/testcontainer:"%(FullPath)"', ' ') /resultsfile:"TestResults\Results.trx""</MsTestCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="MsTestCommand: @(TestAssemblies->'/testcontainer:$(DoubleQuotes)%(FullPath)$(DoubleQuotes)', ' ')" Importance="high"/>
  <RemoveDir Directories="TestResults" Condition="Exists('TestResults')" />
  <MakeDir Directories="TestResults" />        
  <Exec Command="$(MsTestCommand)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

The tests run but I get two weird errors also:

1.

```
EXEC : warning : Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'System.Web.
Mvc' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\projects\conti
nuousdeploymentproof\development\continuousdeploymentproof.web.tests\bin\debug\
continuousdeploymentproof.web.tests.dll' was not found. [C:\Projects\Continuous
DeploymentProof\Development\ContinuousDeploymentProof.msbuild]
```

I suspect this is because Mvc is a NuGet package, but not sure. The DLL does exist in the same place as the tests dll

2.

```
EXEC : warning : Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'log4net' di
rectly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\projects\continuousde
ploymentproof\development\continuousdeploymentproof.web.tests\bin\debug\continu
ousdeploymentproof.web.tests.dll' was not found. [C:\Projects\ContinuousDeploym
entProof\Development\ContinuousDeploymentProof.msbuild]
```

This one is really weird as I never calll log4net directly. I believe its used in some of the OAuth references in the default Mvc termplate. Do I need to directly refernce these in the MSBuild script?